# is cosmosDb thread safe ? (nodeJs)

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to know if it is safe to share the same cosmos db database and container(collection) object in all the application ? thank you

EDIT :
I'm initializing the database when the app starts and putting in the app object (expressjs) then retrieving it in my controllers from req as follow :

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  db.init().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    console.error("Shutting down because there was an error setting up the database.");
    process.exit(1);
  });
  recordsDb.init();
  app.set('db',db);
});
```

in my controller :

```
exports.doDbStuff = async function(req,res){
    const db = req.app.get('db');
    //do stuff..
    res.status(200).end();
}
```

Comment: I presume you are referring to the [Microsoft Azure Cosmos JavaScript SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos)? I also presume you mean "pass instance to modules" as that's actually a little different to "thread safe". So basically you are asking can you "share the connection" as opposed to re-connecting in every function, yes?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, I have added some code, hope you understand what I meant now

Comment: What you have now posted is what I thought you meant. Yes this is perfectly fine and good practice. Has nothing to do with "thread safety" through just for reference. The term "thread safe" actually applies to when you might "fork/spawn" a new running instance of nodejs, or similarly create "threads" with other languages and then share a value with that. Simply passing global instances around in a *single threaded* nodejs environment is perfectly fine. Does not appear to be ( or at least directly ) the official CosmosDB API though. Not that it generally matters

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more question, in my db object I have containers (collection) instance as well, and containerURL (for blob storage) that are initialized iwth the init call at the beginning, can this be a problem ?

Comment: So referencing back to what I just said about "threads", typically the only thing that really matters with "thread safety and database connections" is that you *don't memcopy/fork/spawn* the actual connection instance. Your code does not do that, and you are not memcopy/fork/spawn(ing) anything. So to answers all your questions, *passing around **global variables** is perfectly fine*.